# Less.js not parsing .less files

Tags: wordpress, less

I have tried everything and this makes absolutely no sense! I previously had Less.js working just fine on my site, then I decided to use [WP_Less](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/) because of some of its added features but then ran into issues when implementing [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/). VERY long story (and day) short I am trying to get back to the basics and I can't seem to get Less.js to just work. I've turned off all plugins and removed all the code except what is in the header so there should be no outside conflicts

the header.php has this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );?>/style.css" /> <!-- WP Theme Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );?>/style.css" /> <!-- Theme Less Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );?>/css/less/style.less" /> <!-- Style.JS -->
```

This results in only the the less.js and the default style.css loading **no style.less**:

If I modify the style.less call to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="<?php get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );?>/css/less/style.less" />
```

then they all load but the style.less does not get parsed:

Nothing I have tried down to its simplest form based on their documentation has worked and I simply don't understand why, I've set this up on other sites with no issues before.

If anyone can help you thank you SO MUCH, this is time sensitive and very urgent right now.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Silent fail, nothing in console, files are loaded and are visible to less, less is visible in console (under window.less). `less.refresh()` thinks for a moment but doesn't update styles either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, LESS was silently failing due to parsing errors.

In order to debug less.js, open javascript console in your browser (i.e. F12) and type:

```
less.env = "development";
less.refresh();
```

I've filed a report to `less.js` project, so they could fix this.

Comment: You are a hero. I've spent the past 2+ hours running around in circles trying to figure out why my less files weren't being processed. My less file was referencing a single Bootstrap style that, apparently, was loaded in the wrong order. Your solution took a grand total of about 10 seconds to spot the problem.